# JUnit Testing - What am I doing Wrong in Android

Tags: android, api, unit-testing, junit

May I know what's wrong in this code to test the API.

```
Mockito.`when`(UserRepository.accessToken(loginViewModel.userCredentials.userName.get().toString(), loginViewModel.userCredentials.password.get().toString()))
```

Please help me.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

The format  should be like

```
 when(someMockfun()).thenReturn(mockresult);
```

so

Mockito.`when`(UserRepository.accessToken(loginViewModel.userCredentials.userName.get().toString())).thenReturn(loginViewModel.userCredentials.password.get().toString());

Comment: How to pass the live data in the "thenReturn" method? I want to check my login API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use argument matchers link anyString().

```
Mockito.mockStatic(yourClass.class);
Mockito.when(UserRepository.accessToken(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(...);
```

that will mock your method.